# Take care of an unresolved dependency during ant compile

Tags: hadoop, twitter, ant, ivy

I was trying to build the twitter-corpus-tools found at https://github.com/myleott/twitter-corpus-tools.

These are the steps I have executed so far.

1. Clone the repository in my machine.

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/myleott/twitter-corpus-tool
   ```
2. Change to the cloned directory.

   ```
   cd twitter-corpus-tools/
   ```
3. Start compilation.

   ```
   ant compile
   ```
4. The compilation goes fine with all the messages being spewed out. However, at some point, I get this error message.

> ```
> [ivy:retrieve]    ==== libraries: tried
> [ivy:retrieve]      -- artifact com.cloudera.hadoop#hadoop-mrunit;0.20.2-320!hadoop-mrunit.jar:
> [ivy:retrieve]      /home/masroor/Projects/TREC2011/twitter-corpus-tools/ivy/local-repo/hadoop-mrunit-0.20.2-320.jar
> [ivy:retrieve]        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
> [ivy:retrieve]        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
> [ivy:retrieve]        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
> [ivy:retrieve]        :: com.cloudera.hadoop#hadoop-mrunit;0.20.2-320: not found
> [ivy:retrieve]        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
> [ivy:retrieve] 
> [ivy:retrieve] :: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
> ```

I do not know what to do at this point. I see other reports (including [this one](https://www.google.com.bd/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpiazza.com%2Fclass_profile%2Fget_resource%2Fhbkyg1fhwza2k1%2Fhf1crydnnuj1fv&ei=QZHZVOmmF4KTuQT7jYDgDw&usg=AFQjCNFs7cEBBAymjAvMd73bvlE5pmu_dg&sig2=mbyZQfZp3r2lfSCERq8J1w), slide 22) over the net where people  have successfully carried out this build.

Comment: Perhaps adding this to the ivysettings helps <ibiblio name="public" m2compatible="true" root="https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/libs-release" />

Comment: @HankLapidez I added the line       `<ibiblio name="public" m2compatible="true" root="http://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/libs-release/" />` to `ivy/ivysettings.xml`. (Please note the small changes I made so that my xml editor calls the file to be valid.) But no luck, the error persists.

Comment: https://github.com/isoboroff/twitter-corpus-tools turned out to be a newer one which brought success.